# PYSPARK - Unique Occurrence of a column + 1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

What is the best approach to create a new column in df like the below Count column where it checks all columns in the START column and only increments the count by +1 when a new occurrence is seen.

```
+---------+--------+------+------+
|START    |KEY1    |Color  Count |
+---------+--------+------+------+
| 100     |  1     | White|  1   |
| 100     |  2     | Blue|   1   |
| 101     |  3     | Green|  2   |
+---------+--------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [dense_rank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html#:%7E:text=Window%20function%3A%20returns%20the%20rank,sequence%20when%20there%20are%20ties.)

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
START,KEY1,Color
100,1,Blue
100,2,White
101,3,Green
102,3,Black
101,5,Brown
"""))


sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)
sparkDF.show()

+-----+----+-----+
|START|KEY1|Color|
+-----+----+-----+
|  100|   1| Blue|
|  100|   2|White|
|  101|   3|Green|
|  102|   3|Black|
|  101|   5|Brown|
+-----+----+-----+
```

#### Dense Rank

```
window = Window.orderBy(F.col('START'))
    
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('Count',F.dense_rank().over(window))

sparkDF.show()

+-----+----+-----+-----+
|START|KEY1|Color|Count|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|  100|   1| Blue|    1|
|  100|   2|White|    1|
|  101|   3|Green|    2|
|  101|   5|Brown|    2|
|  102|   3|Black|    3|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

#### Dense Rank - SparkSQL

```
sparkDF.registerTempTable("TB1")

sql.sql("""
    SELECT
        START
        ,KEY1
        ,COLOR
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY START) as COUNT
    FROM TB1
""").show()

+-----+----+-----+-----+
|START|KEY1|Color|Count|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|  100|   1| Blue|    1|
|  100|   2|White|    1|
|  101|   3|Green|    2|
|  101|   5|Brown|    2|
|  102|   3|Black|    3|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
```